# phonegap reach iphone directory

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, cordova

I started to write phonegap apps in xcode. I am writing update checker applications using an server. First I retrieved the application contents with json file in server. Then I need to reach iphone directory in order to compare with server whether this application is there or not. So, how to reach the iphone directory in phonegap. Thanks
ps: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the File api: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#File
You'll need to update the Cordova.plist file:

```
<key>Plugins</key>
<dict>
    <key>File</key>
    <string>CDVFile</string>
</dict>

<key>Plugins</key>
<dict>
    <key>FileTransfer</key>
    <string>CDVFileTransfer</string>
</dict>
```

You can then use the DirectoryReader/FileReader API to check for your files.  Note that iOS sandboxes applications meaning that you'll only be able to see a slice of the file system that's isolated to your application.